# Homework: Awkward formulation of the exercise

Tags: complex-analysis

**The exercise:**

Let $U$ be open and connected, let $\bar D$ be a closed disk contained in $U$ and let $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic. Denote by $γ$ the circle which is the boundary of $D$. Suppose there is a unique point $z_0 \in U$ such that $|f(z)| ≤ |f(z_0)|$ for all $z∈U$. Assume that $z_0 \in D$.

(1) Show that there exists $g : U → C$, analytic on $\bar D$, such that
$$ \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-f(z_0)}=\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}$$

for all $z\in U\setminus \{ z_0 \}$ and $g(z_0) ∈ \mathbb{N}$. Now use the Local Cauchy Formula to conclude that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-f(z_0)}dz \neq 0.$$

(2) Prove the sequence $\{S_N\}$, defined below, converges uniformly on $γ$.

$$ S_N(z)=-\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f'(z)}{f(z_0)}\left(\frac{f(z)}{f(z_0)}\right)^n$$

(3) Show that from 2. it follows that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-f(z_0)}dz = 0.$$

(4) Suppose the set of maxima of $f$ is countable. Prove the Maximum modulus principle for this case using arguments analogous to the above, i.e. show that any non-constant analytic function $f : U → C$ (with $U$ open) with a countable set of maxima does not attain a maximum absolute value.
(Hint for 4: use that if a nonconstant power series $f$ with radius of conv. larger than 0 has $f(0)=0$ the there exists a $r'$ such that for all $|x|<r'$ either $x=0$ or $f(x)\neq 0$).

**My reasoning**
At $z_0$ a series expansion of $f$ exists. Clearly $f'(z_0)=0$ since $z_0$ is a maximum and lies in an open neighborhood on which $f$ is analytic. But equivalently I could inductively argue that all the derivatives must be zero. Then the maximum modulus principle follows immediately. Back to the question however. I see that the integral down becomes

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}dz \neq 0.$$

The integral must be equal however to $g(z_0)$ (CIF). Therefore we expect to find $g(z_0)\neq 0$. I do not really know how they want to proceed. Also I would like to know if you think this exercise makes sense at all, because to me it seems so obvious immediately that $f$ must be constant if its modulus has a maximum on an open set.

**Edit** I edited the question to include the whole homework in order to possible make clear what the aim of the exercise is (it is not clear to me).

Comment: Your last sentence is exactly what I was thinking. By the open mapping theorem or maximum modulus principle, $f$ is constant on a closed ball contained in $U$, whence $f$ is constant on $U$ by connectedness--unless, I am missing something too.

Comment: You are exactly right. The aim of the exercise is to prove this. I can give you the other steps of the suggestions that they make for the proof.

Comment: I don't understand the way they are thinking...

Comment: Quite obviously you are supposed to _prove_ the maximum principle (in (3)). In (1) the sentence 'assume $f$ is not a constant' seems to be missing.

Comment: Yes, I quite got that. The natural thing for me would be to show that we have a power series of $f$ around $z_0$. I would then inductively show that derivatives of any order must be zero, hence $f$ constant. I don't understand the way they want me to do it and it seems contradictionary to me from the beginning.

Comment: I did not get how you want to show (inductively) that all derivatives of $f$ vanish at $z_0$. (And yes, they want you to give a proof by contradiction)

Comment: The first derivative of $f$ at $z_0$ must be zero. If not $|f|$ exceeds $|f(z_0)|$ on an open neigborhood of $z_0$. Assume that we have proven that the $n$-th order derivative is zero. Then by an equivalent argument the $n+1$-th der. must be zero. Since $f$ analytic it must be equal to its power series on a certain radius of convergence. On this disk it must be constant. Since it is constant in a neighborhood of $z_0$ it must be constant on the connected component of $z_0$. $U$ connected -> QED

Comment: Some help is much appreciated because I do not get the reasoning that they want...

Comment: I still don't get your induction proof. What do you mean by 'by an equivalent argument'? For me that's handwaving at the essential point in the induction. Do you know $|f^\prime(z_0)| > |f^\prime(z)|$? How do you even get the case $n=2$?

Comment: Handwaving for you and trivial for me? Dont know... If the series for $f$ is of the form $f=z_0+a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 +...$ then for any neighborhood $N_0$ of $0$  there exists an $x\in N_0 \setminus \{ 0\}$ such that $|f(x)|>|f(0)|$.

Comment: Yes, because you assume $f(0)= 0$. How do you show that $|a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \ldots| > |a_0|$ if $a_0 \neq0$ somewhere? But if it is trivial for you it's fine with me.

Comment: $a_1=0$ (we used induction). Then in some directions $f$ will increase, in others it will decrease. In particular there is a direction in which the modulus increases.

Comment: I'm taking about $a_0$. If $|f(z_0)|=0$ is a maximum then it is in fact trivial that $f$ is constant (and the constant is, quite obviously, $=0$).

Comment: I am looking for some help with the actual exercise, particularly point 1. BTW I assumed nowhere that $f(0)=0$, in fact I assumed that $f(0)=a_0$ (having translated $z_0$ to the origin)

Comment: If you write $f(z) = a_1z + \ldots $ you assume $f(0)=0$, and in your 'induction' you make use of that. From where do you know that? Your induction does not work. And because of that, they propose a different approach.

Comment: I wrote $f(z)=a_0+a_2z^2+...$, right?

Comment: But then again, I don't understand their approach. That is what I am asking help for.

Comment: Yes. But how do you show that the norm of this is $>|a_0|$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ if $a_0 \neq 0$? Because this is not so easy the approach they suggest is to use their reasoning and arrive at the (obvious) contradiction that the integral involving $f^\prime(z_0)$ is $=0$ and cannot be at the same time. You seem to be caught in the idea that you get that trivially with the power series expansion, which I doubt. Just my 2 ct, and now I won't comment any further.